# code 255: the file can not be accessed by the process when commiting .mdf, .ldf database files

Tags: commit, dvcs, tortoisehg

I use mercurial as my DVCS and tortoiseHg. when I'm trying to commit .mdf and .ldf files I get and error:

```
trouble committing "project root"/App_Data/WebStore.mdf!
terminated: "full path"/App_Data/WebStore.mdf: The process can not get access to the file
[command returned code 255 Sun Feb 03 13:57:29 2013]
```

I committed hundreds of times these files but now get this error. Unfortunately I don't remember what I did.

Any ideas about what can trigger such behavior??

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for process, which opened and locked WebStore.mdf. Save work and reboot?

Comment: I've already tried to save and reboot before I saw Your answer - everything worked))